# Slick is failing to find config values in reference.conf (i.e., reference.conf is being ignored), in test setup

Tags: scala, sbt, slick, slick-3.0, typesafe-config

When attempting to execute a query via Slick (v3.0.3), I am receiving a `com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing` exception (wrapped in a `ExceptionInInitializerError`), exclaiming:

```
No configuration setting found for key 'slick'
```

Apparently Slick requires a config value for `slick.dumpPaths` to be present when `debug` logging is enabled. Ordinarily, a default value will be provided by the `reference.conf` file that comes stock in Slick's jar-file, but for some reason that file (or that particular key) is not getting picked up, in this case.

In addition, adding an `application.conf` (which includes the requested config value, `slick.dumpPaths`) to my application's resource directory (`src/main/resources/`, by default) and/or to the test resource directory does not help the problem -- the exception still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was (apparently) happening because I was attempting to run the Slick query via SBT's `Tests.Setup` hook. My hook, in `build.sbt`, looks something like this:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Setup(loader =>
  loader.loadClass("TestSetup").newInstance)
```

My guess is that SBT has not properly instantiated the `classpath` at the time this `TestSetup` class gets instantiated (and when my Slick query tries to execute). Perhaps someone that knows more about SBT's internals can edit this answer to provide more insight, though.